# CSS: series of floated elements without wrapping but rather scrolling horizontally

Tags: css, layout

I'm working on a album viewer. At the top I want a horizontal container of all the image thumbnails. Right now all the thumbnails are wrapped in a div with `float:left`. I'm trying to figure out how to keep these thumbnails from wrapping to the next line when there are too many, but rather stay all in one horizontal row and use the scrollbar.

Here's my code:
(I don't want to use tables)

```
<style type="text/css">
    div {
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    #frame {
        width:600px;
        padding:8px;
        border:1px solid black;
    }
    #thumbnails_container {
        height:75px;
        border:1px solid black;
        padding:4px;
        overflow-x:scroll;
    }
    .thumbnail {
        border:1px solid black;
        margin-right:4px;
        width:100px; height:75px;
        float:left;
    }
    .thumbnail img {
        width:100px; height:75px;
    }
    #current_image_container img {
        width:600px;
    }
</style>
<div id="frame">
    <div id="thumbnails_container">
        <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://www.blueridgexotics.com/images/glry-pixie-bob-kittens.jpg" alt="foo" /></div>
        <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://www.blueridgexotics.com/images/PB-KitJan08-1.jpg" alt="foo" /></div>
        <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://www.blueridgexotics.com/images/PB-KitJan08-3.jpg" alt="foo" /></div>
        <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://www.blueridgexotics.com/images/PB-Jan08.jpg" alt="foo" /></div>
        <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://www.blueridgexotics.com/images/gallery3.jpg" alt="foo" /></div>
        <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://www.blueridgexotics.com/images/gallery4.jpg" alt="foo" /></div>
        <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://www.blueridgexotics.com/Gallery-Pics/kitten3.jpg" alt="foo" /></div>
        <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://www.blueridgexotics.com/Gallery-Pics/kitten1.jpg" alt="foo" /></div>
    </div>
    <div id="current_image_container">
        <img src="http://www.whitetailrun.com/Pixiebobs/PBkittenpics/shani-kits/Cats0031a.jpg" alt="foo" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, so after a couple answers we figured out the thumbnails need to be inline, and then parent needs to have white-space:nowrap set. I would still prefer to be able to use block elements for the thumbnails tho so I can add borders and what not. If you have an answer that uses block element thumbnails I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: A lot of people say to use inline-block... It seems like I've had negative experiences with it before, but I will try it again later today.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

How about using `display: inline-block` this way you can use borders on the block elements and get the horizontal scroll bar.

```
#thumbnails_container {
    height:75px;
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:4px;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    white-space: nowrap
}
.thumbnail {
    border:1px solid black;
    margin-right:4px;
    width:100px; height:75px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: You need to keep in mind that inline-block only works on inline elements in IE7 (so you'll need to use spans and not divs). 

You can also get an inline-block type of layout in IE 6 & 7 by setting the display to inline and triggering hasLayout.

Comment: @gdelfino, is this possible to place thumbnail in two rows.. one thumbnail then second and then the third one start in another column.

Answer (score 6):

Did you try

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

in your #thumbnails_container?

Comment: yeah, only seems to work on text... at least with the doctype im using... perhaps it works with other doctypes

Comment: If you were using images instead of the floated divs it would work, since the IMG is an inline element anyway.

Comment: Ha, yes... I just realized that when the other guy suggested changing my divs to inline. So inline thumbnails, with nowrap whitespace for the parent. Perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of floating, try this:

```
#thumbnails_container {
    height:75px;
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:4px;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
.thumbnail {
    border:1px solid black;
    margin-right:4px;
    width:100px; height:75px;
    display: inline;
}
```

**Remove** the `div { overflow:hidden; }`, the rest stays the same.

It's a bit simpler and they'll span across and scroll like you want.

Comment: Changing the thumbnails to inline was a step. Now that they're inline the white-space:nowrap on the parent can actually work. Both of ya'lls answers together solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is a common mistake thinking that setting the white-space property to "nowrap" also works on floated elements.
It only works on **inline** elements or **inline-block** elements.

I guess you need the floated elements to be a block, so you could turn them into inline blocks.
It is possible to gain it on all the browsers with some trick:

```
display: -moz-inline-stack;
display: inline-block;
zoom: 1;
*display: inline;
```

This solution opens a lot of new web-design sceneries to be explored, so I gratefully give the proper credits to the author:
http://foohack.com/2007/11/cross-browser-support-for-inline-block-styling/

Here you can read a document which speaks of the white-space property and the floated elements:
http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/white-space

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This is driving me nuts, can't figure it out.

This kinda works:

```
.thumbnail {
    padding-right:4px;
    width:100px; height:75px;
    display: table-cell;
}
.thumbnail img {
    border:1px solid black;
    display: block;
    width:100px; height:75px;
}
```

But I have no idea about browser support for display: table-cell;

Personally i would either make the thumbs vertical or use javascript (the browser scrollbar is ugly anyways)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a few months ago. I tried all solutions presented here. They don't work.

This is my solution:

Give the wrapper div the needed width fix (body will expand, too). Then put the content in the extra large wrapper container (float or inline). Now you can use the horizontal scrollbar of the window as scrollbar. Now everything else on the page (header, footer etc.) is scrolling with. You can give these containers position:fixed. Now they stay on there position, while you are scrolling the extra wide wrapper/body.

Comment: Very dirty solution. Btw, OHAI Felix :)

Comment: No not dirty, its elaborated! It works and its in production! Give a better solution.

Comment: I did. It seems awkward to me (as a user) to use the scrollbar at the bottom of my browser to scroll something that is at the top.

Comment: Actually we have big half transparent scroll arrows fixed positioned on the left and right border over the container. But the users use the scroll-wheel of there mice, so we support the scroll wheel for horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Dirty. Better solution: elements with `display: inline;`, parent with `white-space: nowrap;`.

Answer (score 0):

> I would still prefer to be able to use block elements for the thumbnails tho so I can add borders and what not.

You can use "borders and whatnot" with `display: inline-block` elements. You can also use fixed with/height `inline-block` elements, so that your design is consistent.

Basically, make `.thumbnail` not-floated and `display: inline-block`, apply width/height, borders etc., and on `#thumbnails_container` use `white-space: nowrap`.

Answer (score 0):

Add another container for the thumbnails and set it's width to the total width of all thumbnails (along with their margins, borders and padding). Look below at div named "thumbnails_scrollcontainer":

```
<style type="text/css">
div {
    overflow:hidden;
}
#frame {
    width:600px;
    padding:8px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
#thumbnails_container {
    height:75px;
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:4px;
    overflow-x:scroll;
}
.thumbnail {
    border:1px solid black;
    margin-right:4px;
    width:100px; height:75px;
    float:left;
}
.thumbnail img {
    width:100px; height:75px;
}
#current_image_container img {
    width:600px;
}
</style>
<div id="frame">
    <div id="thumbnails_container">
        <div id="thumbnails_scrollcontainer" style="width : 848px;">
            <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://www.blueridgexotics.com/images/glry-pixie-bob-kittens.jpg" alt="foo" /></div>
            <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://www.blueridgexotics.com/images/PB-KitJan08-1.jpg" alt="foo" /></div>
            <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://www.blueridgexotics.com/images/PB-KitJan08-3.jpg" alt="foo" /></div>
            <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://www.blueridgexotics.com/images/PB-Jan08.jpg" alt="foo" /></div>
            <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://www.blueridgexotics.com/images/gallery3.jpg" alt="foo" /></div>
            <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://www.blueridgexotics.com/images/gallery4.jpg" alt="foo" /></div>
            <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://www.blueridgexotics.com/Gallery-Pics/kitten3.jpg" alt="foo" /></div>
            <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://www.blueridgexotics.com/Gallery-Pics/kitten1.jpg" alt="foo" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="current_image_container">
        <img src="http://www.whitetailrun.com/Pixiebobs/PBkittenpics/shani-kits/Cats0031a.jpg" alt="foo" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question now but this came up in a google search. I was trying to change a floated layout into a horizontal scrolled layout on mobile. None of the above worked for me. Instead I used the below which worked in my case:

```css
    main
 {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
 }
 
    main .thumbnail
 {
    width: 400px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

This way worked for me

```
main #thumbnailBox {
height: 154px;
width: auto;
overflow-x: scroll;
white-space: nowrap;}

main .thumbnail {
display: inline-block;}
```