# Zurb Foundation Overflow

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, overflow, zurb-foundation-5

I have a problem where I need to be able to scroll on mobile for a specific piece of content.

So I have a row lets say, the left half of it I want to stay as is - the right half of it will need the content in it to overflow and be able to scroll. So that part of the row would extend out past the screen width and the user could scroll the content.

How would I go about this?

Currently I have my rows setup as I need them but anytime I put more content in the right hand side it tries to push it underneath the current content.

Ignore any custom css they just make changes to base padding.

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-6 columns smallpadding-right">
            <div class="small-5 columns">
            <img class="productImg" src="images/sub_subcategories/airtools.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="small-5 columns font10 nopadding">
            <a href="#">Brooks DeWalt D25123K-GB </a><br />
            <a href="#" class="button tiny">Remove</a>

            </div>
            <div class="small-2 columns smallpadding">
            <img class="arrows" src="images/arrow_up.png"/>
            </a><input class="input-padding" type="text" value="21"/>
            <img class="arrows" src="images/arrow_down.png"/></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="small-6 columns">
            <div class="small-6 columns">
            <img class="productImg" src="images/sub_subcategories/airtools.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="small-6 columns">
            <img class="productImg" src="images/sub_subcategories/airtools.jpg">
            </div>

        </div>
     </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: Side note, you don't double-nest rows. You could have a column before you start another row.

Answer (score 1):

according to  [How to enable overflow scrolling within a Semantic Ui Grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29283128/how-to-enable-overflow-scrolling-within-a-semantic-ui-grid/29354200) and [CSS: series of floated elements without wrapping but rather scrolling horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373379/css-series-of-floated-elements-without-wrapping-but-rather-scrolling-horizontal) (duplicates??)

You should, if i understand your question well be able to fix your issue with the HTML like that shown beneath:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="small-6 columns smallpadding-right">
         <div class="row">     
            <div class="small-5 columns">
            <img class="productImg" src="images/sub_subcategories/airtools.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="small-5 columns font10 nopadding">
            <a href="#">Brooks DeWalt D25123K-GB </a><br />
            <a href="#" class="button tiny">Remove</a>

            </div>
            <div class="small-2 columns smallpadding">
            <img class="arrows" src="images/arrow_up.png"/>
            </a><input class="input-padding" type="text" value="21"/>
            <img class="arrows" src="images/arrow_down.png"/></a>
            </div>
        </div>    
        </div>
        <div class="small-6 columns">
         <div class="row" style="overflow-x:scroll; white-space: nowrap">   
            <div class="small-6 columns" style="display:inline-block; float: none;">
            <img class="productImg" src="images/sub_subcategories/airtools.jpg" alt="1">
            </div>
            <div class="small-6 columns" style="display:inline-block; float: none;">
            <img class="productImg" src="images/sub_subcategories/airtools.jpg" alt="2">
            </div>
            <div class="small-6 columns" style="display:inline-block; float: none;">
            <img class="productImg" src="images/sub_subcategories/airtools.jpg" alt="3">
            </div>
            <div class="small-6 columns" style="display:inline-block; float: none;">
            <img class="productImg" src="images/sub_subcategories/airtools.jpg" alt="4">
            </div>
          </div>  
        </div>
</div>
```

Notice the inline styles `style="display:inline-block; float: none;"` and `style="overflow-x:scroll; white-space: nowrap"` which can be replace with CSS and classes.

Demo: http://sassmeister.com/gist/9530d90ef425eb805da6